# What do these line of codes mean? Decoding newswires back to text

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, decode

```
from keras.datasets import reuters
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words=10000)

word_index = reuters.get_word_index()
reverse_word_index = dict([(value,key)for(key,value)inword_index.items())
decoded_newswire = ''.join([reverse_word_index.get(i-3,'?') for i in train_data[0]])
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand this line

```
decoded_newswire = ''.join([reverse_word_index.get(i-3,'?') for i in train_data[0]])
```

Comment: Please place all of your clarifications in the question itself, not as an answer (what you posted here might be valuable, but... it's not an answer). Actually it looks like you repeated a line of code that's already in your question, so feel free to call attention to that line of code in your question itself, and explain what your specific issue is, as well.